# Difference between putting code at the end of a Task that is awaited versus putting code after the await:

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

Should this block of code...

```
async void SomeMethodAsync() {
    this.IsDoingLongRunningWork = true;
    await Task.Run(() => 
    {
        DoLongRunningWork();
        this.IsDoingLongRunningWork = false;
    });
}
```

...behave differently than this block of code...

```
async void SomeMethodAsync() {
    this.IsDoingLongRunningWork = true;
    await Task.Run(() => 
    {
        DoLongRunningWork();
    });
    this.IsDoingLongRunningWork = false;
}
```

...?

Comment: You'll have to wait however long it takes to marshal the continuation to the original synchronization context.  That could take some time, time in which other things could potentially be changing in other threads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well they may well be executed in different threads, for one thing. If `IsDoingLongRunningWork` affects a user interface (for example) then it should probably only be changed in the UI thread, in which case the first code is incorrect (the new task will run in a thread-pool thread) and the second code is correct (assuming the method is called from a UI thread).

Answer (score 0):

BTW, you have a syntax error in your code. You are missing `);` for each `await` statement.

The answer depends a lot on whether there is a synchronization context. For example, I am pretty sure that if this code is running in a Console application, the code after the `await` statement *could* be executed in a different thread than the code before `await`. However, in a Windows application (which uses a UI thread synchronization context), your code will return to the main UI thread after `await` finishes (assuming the code *before* `await` was executing on the main UI thread).

Without more context, the answer is yes: The code is different. At the very least, make sure `IsDoingLongRunningWork` is thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for the note about the missing );. I've corrected that issue in the original question.